# Block users by domain address in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have a node js application

```
version -  v0.10.35.
Framework - hapi.js framework
Uses bower to manage front-end libraries
```

This has a public set of url's to access, each specific for a customer. When a url is being accessed, it will check with the database and give the relevant output.

In my case there is an ex-customer, from whom I continuously get request for the his specific url. I have the domain address from which the request is sent which would look something like "www.ExampleForExCustomer.com". Is there a way to block the user with this address in Node js ?

The user when tries to access, will get an error message since he is no longer a customer, but this occurs after a db check is done for the customer, and i'm trying to avoid that process

For some complicated reasons, I cannot block the user by IP address on a network level.

I'm quite new to Node js, so it would be really helpful if someone has any insight into a solution for this issue

Comment: Are you using a library like Express, or just raw Node HTTP?

Comment: @joe : The app is built on top of the hapi.js framework

Answer (score 0):

> I have a node js application of version v0.10.35

The maintenance period for that version ended on 2016. There were Node v0.12, io.js v1.0, io.js v2.0, io.js v3.0, Node v4.0, Node v5.0, Node v6.0, Node v7.0 and we'll have Node v8.0 released in a moment. You are 8 major versions behind the current version so don't expect it to work at all.

That having been said, the answer to your question will depend on the framework that you're using. You may be using Express, Connect, Hapi, Restify, Loopback, Koa, http, net or hundreds of other modules - all of which will have a different way to block the request.

You didn't include even a single like of code so I cannot post any specific solution. I can give you a hint in the right direction for Express that is the most popular framework so you are most likely to use it - but as I said you provided too little details.

When you're using Express then you should create a middleware that would inspect the request early in the process, before any database connection takes place. You will have access to the `request` object that has many useful properties that you can inspect. When you want to block the user then you should run `next()` callback with an error. To alow the connection you should run the `next()` callback with no error so that it could be handled by other middleware and request handlers.

See this article for more info:

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated with a bit more information. I'm currently managing this project which was written by my predecessor. I am looking to update it, but currently i have these issues to complete before I can look into updating.

Answer (score 0):

As @rsp already said. You are using a very old version of node ...

Using hapi.js (or also other frameworks), you cannot easily determine the requestors url. What you can do, is to determine the `ip`the request is coming from.

```
var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.info.remoteAddress;
```

This might help you block a specific request address ...